# Неправильное центрирование карты

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Использую Google Maps API в приложении Android. Устанавливаю центр карты, но если координаты центра выше севера Москвы — центр сдвигается ниже (от 30 до 200 км). В остальных точках всё работает превосходно. С чем связано — не понятно.

```
SupportMapFragment fm =
    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = fm.getMap();

CameraUpdate center=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(56.106619, 37.960262));
CameraUpdate zoom=  CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

map.moveCamera(center);
map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что центрирование происходило на событии `OnLoad`.

Answer (score -1):

Расскажите пожалуйста,что изменили?Та же проблема,но чутка иной код
[Мой вопрос на стаке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681627/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-gmaps-android)