# Центровка карты на маркере GMaps Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Скажите пожалуйста,что тут изменить,чтобы карта ставилась на маркер который берется по запросу Json?

```
String lat = jsonObj.getString("lat");
        String lng = jsonObj.getString("lng");
        final String markerPath = jsonObj.getString("path");
        gmap = ((NiceSupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(
                Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
        gmap.moveCamera(center);
        gmap.animateCamera(zoom);
        final MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double
                        .parseDouble(lng)));
        if (markerPath == null || markerPath.equalsIgnoreCase("")
                || markerPath == "null" || markerPath == "") {
            markerOpt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin));
            gpin = gmap.addMarker(markerOpt);
        } else {
            Ion.with(MyDetailActivity.this)
                    .load(getResources().getString(R.string.domain_url)
                            + markerPath).asBitmap()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception arg0, Bitmap bmp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            markerOpt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromBitmap(bmp));
                            gpin = gmap.addMarker(markerOpt);
                        }

                    });
```

С тем что есть,карту центрирует примерно на 300-400км от цели...причем не важно где стоит маркер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была похожая проблема, дело в том что я код центрирования карты находился в OnLoad событии, и карта не успевала прогрузится, а центровка уже была выполнена. Нужно центрировать карту после ее загрузки

Comment: У меня вроде в OnCreate стоит...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/KtWZw37c вот полный код активити есть.

Comment: Странно что на 4.0 андроиде все отлично)